# Understanding item creation in TK TreeCtrl using TCL

Tags: tree, tcl, tk-toolkit

So I am trying to learn TK tree ctrl and got lot of online documentation and sample code but unfortunately none of them explaining the logic behind some of the code. So I created a tk tree with a column and elements and some items as below :

```
set Priv(dlg) [toplevel .topLevel];
set recess $Priv(dlg);

set Priv(tree1) [treectrl $recess.tree1]

grid $Priv(tree1) -sticky news;
grid columnconfigure $recess 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure $recess 0 -weight 1

::at::BOMComparison::CreateElems $Priv(tree1)

for {set i 0} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
  set parent [expr {int(rand()*$i)}]  #THIS IS WHERE I GET CONFUSED
  $Priv(tree1) item create -tag item$i -button auto
  $Priv(tree1) item lastchild $parent item$i
  $Priv(tree1) item text item$i name item$i
}

proc BOAComparison::CreateElems {T} { 
  $T element create rect rect -fill [list grey selected]
  $T element create name text

  set S [$T style create nameStyle]
  $T style elements $S {rect name};
  $T style layout $S rect -detach yes -iexpand xy;
  $T style layout $S name -detach no -iexpand xy -expand e;

  $T column create -tag name -itemstyle $S -text Items
  $T configure -treecolumn first;
}
```

So I create parent at the first statement of for loop. Now strange thing is if I change this statement from :-

```
set parent [expr {int(rand()*$i)}]
```

TO THIS

```
set parent "Module"
```

I get an error saying the item "Module" doesn't exist. So I am trying to figure out what is the difference between $parent being a integer number versus it being a string name. I tried this example from [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6064) but did not find the explanation and was wondering if someone can help and explain that.

### OKAY SO I TRIED SOMETHING LIKE THIS AS PER YOUR EXPLANATION CAPTAIN :

```
set treeHierarchy [::getParentChildRel]; #This returns me a list of parent child relation. {{10 20} {20 21} {20 22} {21 24} {20 25}}. Here 10, 20... are ids of parent and child and these ids are associated with the string names of parent and child so i can get the parent child names out of these ids.  

foreach item $modHierarchy {
  lassign $item parent child;
  set parent [::getName $parent]; #This returns the string name associated with the id. Eg. ModulaA is name associated with id 10.
  set child [::getName $child]; #Same goes for this

  if {[$T item id "tag $parent"] eq ""} { #Create parent if not existing and make it child of root
    set p [$T item create -tag $parent -button auto];
    $T item text $p name $parent
    $T item lastchild root $p
  }
  $T item create -tag $child -button auto
  $T item lastchild "$parent" "$child"  # BUT I GET THE SAME ITEM "Module*" DOESN'T EXIST ERROR HERE. NOT SURE WHY.  
  $T item text "tag $child" name $child
}
```

But if I remove the two statements for getting the name out of id i.e.

```
set parent [::getName $parent]; 
set child [::getName $child];
```

then I get the proper hierarchy of items as follows:

- 10

  - 20

    - 21

      - 24
    - 22
    - 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items get created with an internal incrementing `Id` - it is this `Id` that is used to define what the parent item is. In the tree population code, the `set parent [expr {int(rand()*$i)}]` is getting an integer that is in the range of the previously created items (they number from 1 - we find a random integer less than `$i` which starts from 0).

If you have an item created named "Module", you would need to find its `Id` to use as the `parent` attribute (You could find it using `$Priv(tree1) item id "Module"` - or saving the return value from when you created that item)

Comment: Thanks Captain, i figured out my mistake. I should just change the item name to the name of the items and rest should be the id's only. I tried it and it now works. Thanks again.